# SwiftUI - How to have a view go out its parent container

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to allow a view to go outside the boundary of its parent view. Here is a visual representation of what I would like to achieve:

[image: Visual Representation]

I have the setup shown on screen (1). The red border indicates another view inside my main view (the black border). What I want to do is show the grey view (also with black border) on full screen height when the orange button is pressed even though the grey view also lives inside the red view - the effect as shown on screen (2).

Basically I need to make a view **go outside its parent boundaries**.

Unfortunately, I am only able to achieve the effect from screen (3). The grey view is wrapped in a GeometryReader where I set its height to be equal to the maximum height it could get.

Please **do not** advise me to move the grey view out of the red one so that it is on the root level and then use binding to show/hide the sidebar. This is not something I can do in my project.

Comment: Would you show your current code?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, @Voltron I did resolve this and it turned out perfect. However, I am no longer in the same project and cannot share super specifically how I did it. I remember leveraging shared state and the drawer on the right just being outside of the view. You could play with a ZStack and do it!